# Updating NuGet packages: No package updates are available from the current package source

Tags: nuget, t4mvc

List packages in my solution

```
PM> Get-Package

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                                                       
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                                                       
...
T4MVC                          3.2.0                T4MVC is a T4 template that generates strongly typed helpers for ASP.NET MVC.                                                                                                   
T4MVCExtensions                3.2.0                Runtime helpers used by code generated by T4MVC                
...
```

Check what version of T4MVC is available:

```
PM> Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter T4MVC

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                                                       
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                                                       
...
T4MVC                          3.5.3                T4MVC is a T4 template that generates strongly typed helpers for ASP.NET MVC.                                                                                                   
T4MVCExtensions                3.5.3                Runtime helpers used by code generated by T4MVC                                                                                                                                 
...
```

Trying to update:

```
PM> Get-Package -Updates
No package updates are available from the current package source.
```

What's broken in my installation?

**Update**:

- I use VS Express 2012 for Web Update 2 and NuGet 2.2.40116.9051
- The package updates are not shown in NuGet GUI too.

Comment: I've added version information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in NuGet, here is a bug report from somebody else:
http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3289

The workaround is simple: updates are working for individual projects, not for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried on a test solution, I actually saw the same thing as you. But after cleaning my solution and restarting VS, it started working correctly.

```
PM> Get-Package -Updates

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                                                                                             
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                             
EntityFramework                5.0.0                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.                                                                                                                              
jQuery                         2.0.0                jQuery is a new kind of JavaScript Library....                                                                                                                                                                        
jQuery.UI.Combined             1.10.2               jQuery UI is an open source library of interface components — interactions, full-featured widgets, and animation effects — based on the stellar jQuery javascript library . Each component is built according to jQ...
jQuery.Validation              1.11.1               This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots of option for customization. That makes a good choice if you’re building something new from scratch, but also when you’re t...
Modernizr                      2.6.2                Modernizr adds classes to the <html> element which allow you to target specific browser functionality in your stylesheet. You don't actually need to write any Javascript to use it....                               
T4MVC                          3.5.4                T4MVC is a T4 template that generates strongly typed helpers for ASP.NET MVC.                                                                                                                                         
T4MVCExtensions                3.5.4                Runtime helpers used by code generated by T4MVC
```

So I'm not sure what the deal is, and it probably is a NuGet bug, but at least that might provide a workaround.

Comment: I've cleaned my solution and restarted VS -- still no luck.